# How to test setInterval on a method?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, setinterval, sinon, chai

I have a class

```
class Dummy {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = null;
        this.prop2 = null;
        this.prop3 = setInterval(() => {
            this.method1()
        }, 1000);
    }

    method1() {
        // Method logic
    }
}

var dummyObject = new Dummy();
module.exports = dummyObject;
```

I'd like to write tests to verify that `method1` is being invoked after every 1s.

Following is the test code

```
const dummyObject = require('./dummy.js');

describe("Test setInterval", function () {
    it("Test setInterval", function () {
        const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
        const spy = sinon.spy(dummyObject, 'method1');

        clock.tick(1001);
        expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;

        clock.restore();
    })
})
```

When I run the tests however, I get an error 'Expected false to equal to true' and on further digging I realized I am not able to spy on the method which is being called via setInterval.

Please share any thoughts on what I can do to test this scenario?

Comment: I don't have a good solution, but the problem is that `useFakeTimers` replaces the `setInterval` method, but by the time you call it in your test you have already called the real `setInterval` when you `required` `dummyObject`. There are some less-than-ideal solutions, but as is, I think the code is hard to test cleanly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to work the way you want it to, because the method (`method1`) is already called when you require the module and hence there is no chance to spy it afterwards in your test.

I recommend to refactor your Module to export the class, not the instance like:

```
 module.exports = class Dummy {
      constructor() {
          this.prop1 = null;
          this.prop2 = null;
          this.prop3 = setInterval(() => {
              this.method1()
          }, 1000);
      }

      method1() {
          // Method logic
      }

  }
```

Then in you test, require the class and spy on the method before you instantiate it:

```
  const sinon = require('sinon');
  const Dummy = require('./dummy.js');

  describe("Test setInterval", function () {
      it("Test setInterval", function () {
              const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
              // Spy on the method using the class' prototype
              const spy = sinon.spy(Dummy.prototype, 'method1');
              // Initialize the class and make sure its `constructor` is called after you spied on the method
              new Dummy();

              clock.tick(1001);

              expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;

              clock.restore();

      })

  })
```

Comment: Thanks :) For other reasons in the larger code I need to export an instance and not the class. Still this is useful and I understand the issue with why I cannot test the code in its current form